# Component identification request

Tags: components, identification

Just bought a bunch of transistors and one supposedly to be requested as a 2N7000 general purpose mosfets or J201 FETs... Finally unpacked everything and it came in this smaller than a SOIC8 pinout, micro-smd package. 
Component marking says K27 0N. 
It's very likely a lcd-set mosfet 2n7000, eventually a dual positive-negative pair of mosfets or a dual-in-packs according to some datasheets.
**Couldn't find any datasheets on 6 pin mosfets**. 
Can you help me out finding a datasheet or pinout diagram? thank you.
[image]

Comment: Why don't you request the datasheet from the seller?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

please follow the link to find datasheet.

http://html.alldatasheet.com/html-pdf/308586/WEITRON/2N7002KDW/296/1/2N7002KDW.html

K27 is SMD product type marking information